# Programmatically get Workflow Task Outcomes (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: workflow, task-list

I want to read all the Outcomes from a Workflow Task Outcomes (not only the standard but also the customized outcomes) from a Sharepoint 2010 Workflow Task.

I searched all over the internet but didn't find anything that can help.
If you know something (only if it is theoretically or an idea) please answer!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application i need to do something similar. I have a custom Task List with custom fields and associate the Workflow with this Task List.

Now Inside my workflow code when the Task Completes it triggers my task1CompleteInkove method and inside there i have a reference to a property of type SPWorkflowTaskProperties and access my custom fields as so

```
private Guid CustomCommentsColumnGuidId = new Guid("5AE36B4C-3996-4C25-A13B-FF22A7557773");
string taskcomments = wftp.ExtendedProperties[CustomCommentsColumnGuidId].ToString();
```

CustomCommentsColumnGuidId is a private GUID field set to the GUID of my custom field in my custom Task List.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try your code, thanks. I keep you updated.